# How to get view from Adapter based on position and set selected as true in android?

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a `ListView` and an `Adapter`. I want to get listItem from 
adapter, and set `selected` as `true`. How to do it?
Inside the Activity, i have position, based on position i need to highlight that position row in listview.

```
MyActivity.java


if(drugNames.contains(selectedTCIDynamicStock)){
                        int indexOfDuplicate = drugNames.indexOf(selectedTCIDynamicStock);
                        //tried these two ways
                        /*way 1*/
                        View view1 = rowListView.getChildAt(indexOfDuplicate);
                        view1.setSelected(true);
                        /*way 2*/
                        View v = getViewByPosition(indexOfDuplicate,rowListView);
                        v.setSelected(true);
                        }
```

But i am unable to highlight ListView row based on position in activity.

```
Note: Here i am not touching the listview
```

Comment: actually you can't do like this because in `ListView` views are re-used..possible solution will be create one more field in your pojo and get/set boolean there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this line of code... my problem is resolved

```
rowListView.performItemClick(rowListView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, rowListView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
```